# Compilation issue with c pset

Tags: c, cs50

I have no idea why this won't compile, looks fine to me.Want to make a program that builds a pyramid like the one at the end of Super Mario levels. Will ask user
    for a number and then build pyramid to that height.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

/*Want to make a program that builds a pyramid like the one at the end of Super Mario levels. Will ask user
for a number and then build pyramid to that height. for example user inputs 4 then pyramid would be 
   **
  ***
 ****
*****

*/
int main (void)
{
    int input = 0;
    int block = 2;

    /* Asks user for a number between 0 and 24 and stores it as int input. If the number is not between
    0 and 24 then it tells them to try again until it is between 0 and 24*/

    do{
        while(input == 0) 

                                      {
      printf("\n\nEnter a number between but not including 0 and 24 and then press enter:\n\n");
      scanf("%i", &input);
                                      }

        while(input <1 || input > 23) {
        printf(" That number is not between 1-24! Try again idiot");
                                      }
      }

   /* this is the algorithm that builds the pyramid*/

         for(int x = 0; x < input; x++) 
    {

              for(int x = 0; x < input -1; x++) 
              { 
              printf(" ");
              }

              for(int x = 0;x < block;x++)
              {
              printf("#"); 
              }


        printf("\n");
        gap = gap -1;
        block = block +1;
    }
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
$ clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c99 -Wall -Werror    mario.c  -lcs50 -lm -o mario
mario.c:35:10: error: expected 'while' in do/while loop
         for(int x = 0; x < input; x++) 
         ^
mario.c:20:5: note: to match this 'do'
    do{
    ^
1 error generated.
$
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: @ Olaf I added the compiler error message

Comment: where is the while for do/while loop?

Comment: @ Aritra Chakraborty in the script. Can you not see it?

Comment: Read the error message again, check your statements, especially that `do { ... }` part. Aren't it missing something?

Comment: Then when you fixed your compilation error, you need to check your logic, especially inside that non-existent `do...while` loop.

Comment: @Éanan Halferty do While Syntax is do{..}while(..); Those 2 whiles are regular whiles. while{..}.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I have looked at it, for a long time believe me and I still don't know what's wrong. Please help me man

Comment: You have `do { ... } for ...`, where's the `while`? I suggest you change your indentation, it will make it much easier to see these kind of problems.

Comment: You should usually end non-prompting `printf()` format strings with a newline to ensure the output appears timely.  You should always check the return value from `scanf()` so that if the user types `abracadabra` instead of a number, the program won't spin out of control.  Your second while loop never changes `input`; if the loop is entered, it will not exit until you interrupt your program.  The messages about the valid range (1..23) are inconsistent.  You say "between but not including 0 and 24" and also "not between 1-24".  Don't call users idiots, even in jest (see http://thedailywtf.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you constructed your do / while loop incorrectly. Here is how a do / while loop works:

```
do
{
   // Your statements here

} while( condition );
```

Notice that the while comes after the closing } bracket. "condition" should be true to continue the loop or false to end it.

If you look at your code you'll see that after the closing } for the do, you have a for loop. The compiler was expecting a while there. But, you put the while inside the loop.

Here is your code with some comments:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

/*Want to make a program that builds a pyramid like the one at the end of Super Mario levels. Will ask user
for a number and then build pyramid to that height. for example user inputs 4 then pyramid would be 
   **
  ***
 ****
*****

*/
int main (void)
{
    int input = 0;
    int block = 2;

    /* Asks user for a number between 0 and 24 and stores it as int input. If the number is not between
    0 and 24 then it tells them to try again until it is between 0 and 24*/



    /***  You start a do loop here ***/
    do{
        while(input == 0) /*** What does this do??? ***/

                                      {
      printf("\n\nEnter a number between but not including 0 and 24 and then press enter:\n\n");
      scanf("%i", &input);
                                      }

        while(input <1 || input > 23) {
        printf(" That number is not between 1-24! Try again idiot");
                                      }


      /*** You ended your do loop here and so the compiler is ***/
      /*** expecting to see a while. Look at my little sample ***/
      /*** do / while loop above ***/
      }
      /*** You need to add this... ***/
      while(some_condition);
      /*** The some_condition evaluates to true or false and ***/
      /*** controls whether or not the loop continues or ends ***/



   /* this is the algorithm that builds the pyramid*/



        /*** Because you have no while above, the thing the ***/
        /*** compiler sees right after the closing } of the ***/
        /*** do loop is this for, which is not valid ***/
         for(int x = 0; x < input; x++) 
    {

              for(int x = 0; x < input -1; x++) 
              { 
              printf(" ");
              }

              for(int x = 0;x < block;x++)
              {
              printf("#"); 
              }


        printf("\n");
        gap = gap -1;
        block = block +1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry man, I'm a complete beginner and I'm a bit lost. Could you edit my code so that I can see exactly what you mean? Would be much appreciated

Comment: I can but not as a comment. I'll edit my answer for you.

Comment: Okay, the site came back for write access and I have edited my answer as promised. Read my comments carefully, and compare what I wrote to the compiler messages. Let me know if you're still confused. I need to run an errand or two, I'll be back a bit later. If this works for you please help me out and accept the answer :-)

Comment: Oh, this little edit I made will fix this compiler issue, but there may be others and you really need to carefully trace through your logic.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Can you return the favor can accept my answer?